# Correctly Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON

```
{
    "warnings": {},
    "item": {
        "@class": "com.somePackage.model.SomeObject",
        //some fields...
        "comments": [

        ],
        "otherObjects": [{
            "@class": "com.somePackage.model.ObjectSmt",
            //some other fields...
        }]
    }
}
```

And I want to deserialize it into ItemResponse.class

```
public class ItemResponseDto {
private Map<String, List<String>> warnings;
private AbstractItem item;

public ItemResponseDto() {
    this.warnings = new HashMap();
}

public ItemResponseDto(AbstractItem item) {
    this.item = item;
    this.warnings = new HashMap();
}

public AbstractItem getItem() {
    return this.item;
}

public void setItem(AbstractItem item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public Map<String, List<String>> getWarnings() {
    return this.warnings;
}

public void setWarnings(Map<String, List<String>> warnings) {
    this.warnings = warnings;
}
```

}

AbstractItem :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
use = Id.CLASS,
include = As.PROPERTY,
property = "@class")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class AbstractItem implements Serializable{...
```

When I'm trying to deserialize :

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS)
    .readValue(response.asString(), ItemResponseDto.class);
```

I get this exception :

> Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Map

Ok, I can get rid of warnings, but when I'm trying to deserialize object

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
                .readValue(response.asString(), ItemResponseDTO.class)
```

I'm also getting error :

> Unexpected token (END_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.util.List)
>
> path : com.somePackage.model.ItemResponseDTO["item"]
>
> path : com.somePackage.model.SomeObject["comments"]

I guess since **comments** field doesn't contains @class field I get this error

So, is there any way I can ignore this message or smt? Even when I'm trying to parse only object I get errors, that refers to **comments** field. I only have a compiled code, so I cannot edit it.

Comment: Maybe problem is that you are using `AbstractItem` and `AstAbstractItem` in DTO at the same time?

Comment: Nope, that was just a typo